# Remove whitespaces in the beginning of every string in a file in python?

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, toolstrip

How to remove whitespaces in the beginning of every string in a file with `python`?

I have a file `myfile.txt` with the strings as shown below in it:

```
 _ _ Amazon.inc  
Arab emirates
 _ Zynga  
Anglo-Indian
```

Those underscores are spaces.

The code must be in a way that it must go through each and every line of a file and remove all those whitespaces, in the beginning of a line.

I've tried using `lstrip` but that's not working for multiple lines and `readlines()` too.

Using a `for` loop can make it better?

Comment: I was going to suggest using `lstrip()`, but it seems that you've already tried that. Can you post the code you have now so we can make suggestions instead of having to write it again?

Comment: Please remember to upvote and mark the most useful answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is read the lines of the file one by one and remove the leading whitespace for each line. After that, you can join again the lines and you'll get back the original text without the whitespace:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    line_lst = [line.lstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
    lines = ''.join(line_lst)

print lines
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your input data is in infile.txt, and you want to write this file to output.txt, it is easiest to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
inf = open("infile.txt")
stripped_lines = [l.lstrip() for l in inf.readlines()]
inf.close()

# write the new, stripped lines to a file
outf = open("output.txt", "w")
outf.write("".join(stripped_lines))
outf.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

To read the lines from `myfile.txt` and write them to `output.txt`, use

```
with open("myfile.txt") as input:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
        for line in input:
            output.write(line.lstrip())
```

That will make sure that you close the files after you're done with them, and it'll make sure that you only keep a single line in memory at a time.

The above code works in Python 2.5 and later because of the `with` keyword. For Python 2.4 you can use

```
input = open("myfile.txt")
output = open("output.txt", "w")
for line in input:
    output.write(line.lstrip())
```

if this is just a small script where the files will be closed automatically at the end. If this is part of a larger program, then you'll want to explicitly close the files like this:

```
input = open("myfile.txt")
try:
    output = open("output.txt", "w")
    try:
        for line in input:
            output.write(line.lstrip())
    finally:
        output.close()
finally:
    input.close()
```

---

You say you already tried with `lstrip` and that it didn't work for multiple lines. The "trick" is to run `lstrip` on each individual line line I do above. You can try the code out [online](http://ideone.com/5ZjOJ) if you want.

Comment: I guess you must use Python 2.4 which doesn't have the with keyword. I'll rewrite.